# UML modeling tool which can convert a collaboration diagram into a sequence diagram (and back)

Tags: macos, uml

I was reading about UML Collaboration diagrams and what all of the tutorials mention is that a sophisticated UML modeling tool can easily convert a Collaboration diagram into a sequence diagram. I have looked around at a few and haven't found one that can do this which also runs on a Mac.

If you are aware of such a piece of software, which is still being actively developed, I would be interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a sequence diagram to a collaboration diagram but not a collaboration diagram to a sequence diagram.
It is also possible to display a method either in a sequence or a collaboration diagram. It seems to me that the collaboration diagram has been replaced in UML 2 by the communication diagram.
I have EclipseUML Omondo as my company modeling tool.

Comment: So, can EclipseUML generate a collaboration / communication diagram from a sequence diagram automatically?

Comment: I will have a look today and will come back to you when I find out how to do it.

Comment: You need to select a method in the Package explorer > Generate Communication Diagram. There is also another menu if you click on the background of the sequence diagram which will transform your sequence diagram into a collaboration/communication diagram. I use it with Windows and other team mates with Mac and it works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at MagicDraw?  I don't know if it covers your request, but it's one of the more full-featured ones out there.

Comment: Unfortunately, MagicDraw cannot do this.